# How to avoid (single) mouse click processing on double click in browser JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, browser

If the user **double** clicks an HTML button, the **single** click event listener gets called before the double click event listener.

Is there a way to skip single click processing on double click (without jumping through hoops)?

Keep in mind that *I want to be able to react to the single click*, if user does not double click!

Take a look at the self-explanatory [sample at jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/mnuon8wy/).

```
myEventButton.addEventListener(
    'click',
    function(/*e*/)
    {
        myClickDiv.innerHTML = 'Clicked.'; // Gets here first on double click.
    });

myEventButton.addEventListener(
    'dblclick',
    function(/*e*/)
    {
        myDblClickDiv.innerHTML = 'Double clicked.'; // Gets here last on double click.
    });
```

Comment: From what I'm reading, a way to solve this is to add a *slight* delay event in the single click, and have a flag `dblclick = false`. If the doubleclick event is triggered, set `dblclick = true` and prevent the code in the single click event from running

Answer (score 0):

Here is [a solution](https://jsfiddle.net/mnuon8wy/2/)

I don't know if there is a proper way of doing it, but this works. The idea is to keep a timer between clicks, and you forbid any clicks faster than that. This means that when double clicking, the first click will be registered, but the second, being too fast, will be ignored.

Of course you could abstract this behind a nice function, but you get the idea.

Your modified code:

```
// Added variables to store timers
var minTimeBetweenClicks = 1000;
var lastClickTime = Date.now();

myClearButton.addEventListener(
    'click',
    function()
    {
        myClickDiv.innerHTML = '';
        myDblClickDiv.innerHTML = '';
    });

myEventButton.addEventListener(
    'click',
    function(/*e*/)
    {
      // Check the timer before doing anything
      if (Date.now() - lastClickTime > minTimeBetweenClicks) {
        myClickDiv.innerHTML += ' Clicked.';
        lastClickTime = Date.now();
      }
    });

myEventButton.addEventListener(
    'dblclick',
    function(/*e*/)
    {
        myDblClickDiv.innerHTML = 'Double clicked.';
    });
```

PS: I also modified your click code to add "clicked" to the button, so you can see that the double click doesn't  add it twice.

Comment: Sorry, but at least your jsfiddle does not work reliably in my browser (Firefox). But I get the idea, thanks.